# Facebook graph API: adding properties (such as links) to post

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add some links to a video description i'm sharing on facebook by adding a list of properties to the request I'm sending to FB such as:

```
params['properties'] = [{'text': 'Google', 'href': 'https://google.com'}]
```

and sending the params as POST data.

The post goes live but I can't see the properties I've added, is there a way to debug it?

Is there another way to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks

Comment: is the properties parameter something official? where did you read about it?

Comment: there is no such field as "text", only "description" for video

Comment: the properties filed is described at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/post

but I don't understand how it can be used to add link in post description.